# Jquery cannot select input element inside form but select when outside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

click event triggers on a submit button when its outside form, but when its inside form, jquery simply does'nt work!

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(function(){
    //do something
}); 
  });
```

This dont work:

```
<form id="submitForm">
            <input type="email" name="email">
            <input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

This Works! :

```
<form id="submitForm">
            <input type="email" name="email">
</form>         
<input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit">
```

Why is it so? How can I make it work?

Comment: it should work... try to put an alert stmt in the click handler... only problem when submit button is inside a form is, the form will get submitted... so try to prevent it by returning `false` or by calling `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: @mustafa mukadam, just change type from if submit button from `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger the form submittion by `.submit`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       //do something
    }); 
});
```

and you can still use it inside the form

```
<form id="submitForm">
     <input type="email" name="email"/>
     <input id="btn" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: simplets solution is to change the type from submit to button.

Comment: Thanx! e.preventDefault() did the job.

Comment: Urwell, glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

That's because a `type=submit` button or input for that matter, *inside* the form, triggers a post back to the back-end or the server.

And that's exactly the reason why your event callback is seemingly not working, when it actually is.

Use the below to prevent the submission of the form.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ajax stuff
});
```

Comment: But the submit button's click handler will still get called... OP is saying that is not happening

Comment: @ArunPJohny nope. He says that the second code snippet works, while the first doesn't, the reason being the page is being refreshed/

Comment: So then how to use a submit inside form. I dont want to use action="..." Am using ajax to submit form data to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $("#submitForm").submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
```

and

```
$("#btn").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
```

both worked. (changing type="submit" to type="button" didn't).